# Change panels with one button of a click

Tags: vb.net, button, click, panel

I'm currently making a program and I'm adding a utilities form and I have buttons and panels. 1 button for 1 panel so I have code if they click a button while another panel is visible to hide and show the other panel. For some reason I have to click the button twice for it to change to a different panel, not sure why.

Code:

```
Private Sub btnAbout_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAbout.Click
    If pnlAbout.Visible = False Then
        pnlAbout.Visible = True
    Else
        If pnlProfile.Visible = True Then
            pnlProfile.Visible = False
            pnlAbout.Visible = True

            If pnlUpdates.Visible = True Then
                pnlUpdates.Visible = False
                pnlAbout.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnProfile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProfile.Click
    If pnlProfile.Visible = False Then
        pnlProfile.Visible = True
    Else
        If pnlAbout.Visible = True Then
            pnlAbout.Visible = False
            pnlProfile.Visible = True

            If pnlUpdates.Visible = True Then
                pnlUpdates.Visible = False
                pnlProfile.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnUpdates_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdates.Click
    If pnlUpdates.Visible = False Then
        pnlUpdates.Visible = True
    Else
        If pnlAbout.Visible = True Then
            pnlAbout.Visible = False
            pnlUpdates.Visible = True

            If pnlProfile.Visible = True Then
                pnlProfile.Visible = False
                pnlUpdates.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be summarized to:

```
Private Sub btnAbout_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAbout.Click
    pnlAbout.Visible = True
    pnlProfile.Visible = False
    pnlUpdates.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub btnProfile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProfile.Click
    pnlAbout.Visible = False
    pnlProfile.Visible = True
    pnlUpdates.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub btnUpdates_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdates.Click
    pnlAbout.Visible = False
    pnlProfile.Visible = False
    pnlUpdates.Visible = True
End Sub
```

You need twice cause the first click makes the correct panel visible and the second (if you are lucky) the one which was visible not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be Summarize into this:

```
private sub button1_click(Byval sender as System.Object, ByVAl e AS System.EventArgs)Handles buttonUpdates.click

    panel1.Visible = true
    panel2.Visible = false

End Sub
```